# Disable ohead on a single page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

i try to disable the ohead on the first page of a section (and only the first page). I tried a lot of things(e.g. \thispagestyle) but nothing really works.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,parskip=half,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,headings=normal]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{section}
\clearscrheadfoot 
\ihead{Mr. XY} 
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark} 

\begin{document}

\section{first}
%here comes a lot of text...
%ein I don't want to have "first" in the header
\section{second}
%here comes a lot of text again...

\end{document}
```

Hope that someone can give me a solution for that problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want/need chapters? They always start on a new page and don't have a header by default.

Comment: I want to have a header an the start of a section, but only with the name (ihead) and not with the section title (ohead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example uses page style `plain.scrheadings`, which can be defined using the optional arguments of `\ihead` and `\ohead`.

Then, it patches `\section` to append `\thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}` to remove the `\headmark` in the header from pages with section starts.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  parskip=half,
  bibliography=totoc,
  listof=totoc,
  headings=normal
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
  headsepline, plainheadsepline,
  footsepline, plainfootsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{section}
\clearscrheadfoot 
\ihead[Mr. XY]{Mr. XY} 
\ohead[]{\headmark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\let\orgsection\section
\def\section#1#{%
  \auxsection{#1}%
}
\def\auxsection#1#2{%
  \orgsection#1{#2}%
  \thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{first}
\lipsum[2-12]
\section{second}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I bet the users menas on the first page of each section. I.e. what a chapter does.