# Skip headmark on section definition page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

Is it possible to skip the headmark only on the section definition page?

```
%KLASSE DOCUMENT
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered, twoside]{scrartcl}

%TWOSIDE HANDLING
\raggedbottom %TWOSIDE VSPACES ISSUE
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} %HEADER & FOOTER STYLE
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot %CLEAR HEADER & FOOTER
\chead{\headmark} %CENTER CHAPTER IN HEADER
\automark[section]{section} %LINKE SEITE / RECHTE SEITE
\cfoot{\pagemark} %CENTER PAGE IN FOOTER
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------------------- INHALTSVERZEICHNIS
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Third Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\section{Fourth Section}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Fourth Subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You only need to put `\thispagestyle{empty}` directly before `\tableofcontents`. Or `\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}` which also works when the table of contents runs over more than one pages.

Comment: It seems  `scrreprt` and the use of `\chapter` would suit you perfectly.

Comment: @marmot `\thispagestyle{empty}` do the job but it removes also the `pagenumber` and the `headsepline`. @Johannes_B change to `scrreprt` & `\chapter` have to heavy impact to my main project and it have the same issue like `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: this finally solve my problem: [Disable ohead on a single page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340001/disable-ohead-on-a-single-page). Sorry for duplicate.